# since the above codes can successfully match the regex "hello",then why the below codes won't match "world"?

Tags: python

```
import re
m = re.match(r'hello', 'hello world')
print m.group()
```

since the above codes can successfully match the regex "hello",then why the below codes won't match "world"?

```
import re
m = re.match(r'world', 'hello world')
print m.group()
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Comment: "If zero or more characters at the BEGINNING of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance"

Answer (score 1):

From the [**documentation**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) (emphasis mine):

> If zero or more characters **at the beginning** of string match this regular expression, return a corresponding MatchObject instance.

Since "world" is not at the beginning of the string, it does not match. You maybe looking for [`search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) instead.

Comment: Thank you so much this is my first stackoverflow question and your answer encouraged me a lot in additional to the code itself.